Helly number of closed unit balls in R^d
Does anyone know the Helly number of closed unit balls in $\mathbf{R}^d$ and a reference? This number is the smallest number $k(d)$ so that for any collection of of closed unit balls in $\mathbf{R}^d$, if any $k(d)$ of them intersect non-trivially, then all of them intersect non-trivially. So when $d = 1$, $k(d) = 2$ since if you have a collection of closed unit intervals, any two of which intersect non-trivially, then they all share a common point.

For R^2 we need 3 disks, any 2 of which intersect but there is nothing in common to all 3. So putting 3 balls of radius 1 at the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side 2 works. I don't see the purpose of the 4th ball at the center, or the extension to R^3.

Well, the circumradius of a regular unit simplex grows with the dimension. So, for a given regular unit d-simplex, the configuration of balls at the vertices with the radii equal to the circumradius of a regular unit (d-1)-simplex seems to give an example of configuration showing that $k(d)\geq d+1$. The opposite bound is given by the Helly theorem.

By circumradius I assume you mean the distance from the centroid to a vertex. I do believe this is correct and solves the problem. Do you know of a source for this to use as a reference?
